Windows files no longer accessible through Ubuntu 24.04 but they were before, why?
Installed Ubuntu 24.04 as dual boot with windows on my ssd about a month ago. At first I had access to my windows files while in ubuntu via the SSD icon but now it says "Failed to mount windows, error mounting /dev/... wrong fs type, bad option, bad....or other error"
I have changed a few display settings since it last worked in the quest for scroll bars, but that's all.
Edit: I have double checked that fast start is not enabled in windows
Ubfan1: I don't seem to have bitlocker so it's no that.

Maybe bitlocker got turned on for Windows?

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

it shouldn;'t have been and of course it worked fine before but maybe windows updated without my consent - it does that.

This link to my answer and other answers to the same question may be helpful to solve your problem. If the problem is a corrupted file system 'more than dirty', I think it is best to use Windows chkdsk /f to repair a Microsoft file system.

I run into this with my external HDD every time I leave it plugged in before powering up.  For some reason Linux glitches and doesn't recognize the header info, and to fix it I have to go to "repair filesystem" on the volume using Disks.
For some reason the repair filesystem option doesn't fix it (on my machine) using either KDE Partition Manager or gparted.

I had a look at Disks but I don't have "repair file system" option.

In the bottom left of the volume box is a button with a triangle to mount the volume or a square to unmount it, immediately to the right of that is a button with no markings on it.  That's where the Edit Partition - Edit Mount Options - Repair Filesystem - Create Partition Image - etc, are located.

Thanks Misha Hess, that did it !. I now need to find out what was wrong with the filesystem, there is no reason that I know of for it to need repair.

I doubt the problem is with the filesystem itself, since every time this happens to me (being an external drive) I can plug it into any other machine or OS and it reads just fine - it's only the PC that initially booted with the drive connected that has the issue.
Obviously yours isn't external so you can't easily test it with another box, but if the problem occurs again reboot into Windows and see if it's accessible there.  If it is, there's nothing wrong with the filesystem and it's just something Linux is doing wrong in trying to read it.

Yes it boots into windows and everything is accessible so it's a Linux issue. Any ideas where to look for the fault? I will find it annoying having to repeatedly "fix" to access stuff on the windows disk and if there is an actual permanent fix that would be great.

I haven't put this to the test, but it looks like some people found a permanent solution by going to Disks, selecting "edit mount options" and turning off "User Session Defaults"
